# C Programming Problems

Tags: c

I am creating a program and I have finally got to the end of the program, but code blocks keeps giving me an error at the end or on the last line of my program.  Can someone please instruct me or show me where I am going wrong with this code.  Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 50

struct student{
char name[30];
int rollno;
int sub[3];
int total;
};

void main()

{

int i, j, max, count, tot=0, n, a[SIZE],ni;
struct student st[SIZE];

prinf("Enter how many students:");
scanf("%d, &n");


for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    tot=0;
    printf("\nEnter name and roll number for student %d:", i+1);
    scanf("%s", &st[i].name);
    scanf("%d", &st[i].rollno);

for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++){
    printf("Enter marks of student %d for subject %d:", i+1, j+1);
    scanf("%d", &st[i].sub[j]);
    tot=tot+st[i].sub[j];

}
        st[i].total=tot;

    }

    printf("\n\n\n");

for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Student %d Name:%s\n", i+1,st[i].name);
        printf("Student%d Rollno: %d\n", i+1, st[i].rollno);
        printf("marks of subject %d: %d\n", j+1, st[i].sub[j]);
    }

    printf("Total marks: %d\n\n", st[i].total);
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe all you need is to format your code _properly_, then problem should be clear. Atm, it's pretty much unreadable.

Comment: Would make sense to tell us what the error is right?

Comment: In your final loop, j us going to have the value it had upon exit from the previous loop, which is 3 (assuming n > 0).  So your index will be out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

I count five `{` characters and six `}` characters. That's not going to work out well for you :-)

Probably the easiest solution is to get rid of the spurious `}` at the end. It won't solve *all* your problems but it's most likely the cause of the *specific* problem you asked about, the "error at the end or on the last line of my program".

Answer (score 0):

Possible correction:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 50

struct student{
    char name[30];
    int rollno;
    int sub[3];
    int total;
};

int main(void) /* use standard int main(void) instead of implementation-defined void main() */

{

    int i, j, max, count, tot=0, n, a[SIZE],ni;
    struct student st[SIZE];

    printf("Enter how many students:"); /* prinf -> printf */
    scanf("%d", &n); /* the position of " was wrong */


    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        tot=0;
        printf("\nEnter name and roll number for student %d:", i+1);
        scanf("%s", st[i].name); /* &st[i].name is char (*)[30], but %s expects char* */
        scanf("%d", &st[i].rollno);

        for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++){
            printf("Enter marks of student %d for subject %d:", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &st[i].sub[j]);
            tot=tot+st[i].sub[j];

        }
        st[i].total=tot;

    }

    printf("\n\n\n");

    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Student %d Name:%s\n", i+1,st[i].name);
        printf("Student%d Rollno: %d\n", i+1, st[i].rollno);
        for (j=0;j<=2;j++) /* add loop */
            printf("marks of subject %d: %d\n", j+1, st[i].sub[j]);
        printf("Total marks: %d\n\n", st[i].total); /* put this line inside the loop */
    }


    return 0; /* add return 0; */
}
/* remove junk } */
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you for pointing it. I updated my answer.